Flutter - Crashpad Minidump
I got this log in the Android Studio console after my flutter app crashed.
F/crashpad(13848): -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
F/crashpad(13848): )iyJn(iisn.xdSoWb75'DO^9=Xej55E:y7)qM`09j*p~[mm{3R:_e|5_k/j7{j1Ns/xWFEbk:_KT^EqE+@uuffc4TgxsGVyZxi@I.x3kDgUdagcl|u76`g_2jfEU~,"35r*F8!="/8Es[X@KFbY{G!Aq[/I4Cb!!!Y2!Dhm6D!1Yg!m;8!4yw:C+q)$!d%Q9^(g4WL[\q6ign6Dm-X3!7\*i!p#!`FcLuV]On6l?C^V%}/%!9p4!y$o+$EbAobXmzz;
...
F/crashpad(13848): -----END CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----

What can i do with this minidump? How can i make it human readable?
